# Stringify error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this array of hashes:

```
object = [
  {:user_id=>9, :timesheet_project_id=>4, :timesheet_task_id=>87, :date=>"2017-08-23", :time_spent=>2.0, :comment=>"Test 23"}, 
  {:user_id=>9, :timesheet_project_id=>4, :timesheet_task_id=>87, :date=>"2017-08-23", :time_spent=>2.0, :comment=>"Test 23"}
]
```

I am trying to create a new object of the SheetEntry and save it in the model by doing:

```
 def self.save_entry(object)
   entry=SheetEntry.new(object)
   entry.save!
 end
```

But getting this error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `stringify_keys' for Array)

Comment: `object` is an Array, and `SheetEntry#new` method expects a Hash as argument. (reproduce this error by doing `SheetEntry.new([1,2,3])`). You must loop through the `object` (which is an array of hashes) before calling the `save_entry` method or make this method handle the Array type argument.

Comment: is it possible to convert this array to hash?

Comment: I guess that you want to create an object with each element of the array, is that correct?

Comment: yes each hash is a new object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the array so you can create an object with each hash it contains, for example:

```
def self.save_entry(object)
  object.each do |item| 
    SheetEntry.create!(item)
  end
end
```

Notice that using `create!` is equivalent to creating a new object and then saving it (i.e. `new` then `save!`).

As pointed out by MrYoshiji, it would be better to change the method name to `save_entries`, which indicates it will handle multiple objects.

Comment: please don't use a singularized method name when its logic is meant to handle several objects. Either call this method `save_entries(objects)` or do the loop outside of the `save_entry` method. A method name should be enough to understand its logic and usage, having to read the source code to understand is a sign of bad naming.

Comment: @MrYoshiji You are right, thanks for pointing this out; i'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help!